# Use of new_table, old_table, the original table name in a after trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm writing a trigger function in **PosgreSQL** for an **after** trigger that handles **UPDATE/ INSERT** and want to reference the new table by its **original name** instead of **new_table**. And I wasn't able to find anything about that in the documentation. Is this possible?

In the same situtation, I want to know if new_table is available to use in an before trigger procedure. If so, what does the original table name refer to in this case, the new one or the current (before UPDATE/ INSERT) one?

Thanks a bunch in advanced.

Comment: Are you talking about a row level trigger or a statement level trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html) you can rename the OLD / NEW pseudotables with `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS whatever`

OLD and NEW are available in a before trigger too; if youbset alternative values in the NEW table it will influence the data that ends up being written to the table